# An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header in SoapUI

Tags: soap, soapui, ws-security

I try to intercept encrypted soap message in wildfly 10 with soapUI. Deployment is successful.

First below pics are outgoing ws-security configuration which includes signature and encryption.

```
* Signature
Keystore - client keystore
Alias - alias of client's private key
Password - password of client's private key
Key Identifier Type - X.509
Parts - arg0 (Name), Body (Encode)
```

[image]

```
* Encryption
Keystore - client keystore
Alias - alias of server's public key
Password - Empty (no password required for public key)
Key Identifier Type - X.509
Parts - arg0 (Name), Body (Content)
```

[image]

The final pic shows incoming WS-Security Configuration.

```
Decrypt Keystore - client keystore
Signature Keystore - client keystore
Password - password of client's private key
```

[image]

But the returned response is soap-fault like following

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
         <faultstring>An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there some process which I missed?

### Update

This is soap request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://soap.aaa.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568147641">
MIICxzCCAa+gAwIBAgIENlXkmDANBgkqUg35Lpg==
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568147640" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/>
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference><wsse:Reference URI="#374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568147641" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>gBZkBwQh+A==
</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:ReferenceList>
<xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568147642"/>
</xenc:ReferenceList>
</xenc:EncryptedKey>
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="X509-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568146635">MIICzTCCAskwggGxo
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<ds:Signature Id="SIG-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568146639" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568146638">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>EiWlHfC/AfhBC2bOo2R6CHDe06s=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>WSnRVBSZlF2XXxvkH0Udi8gsRwvsKzJ9KnjXPZIbz/msx5VpjhgcTVOgPQW1myUVVwSD20XQ==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568146636">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="STR-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568146637" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
<wsse:Reference URI="#X509-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568146635" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<soap:sayHello>
<!--Optional:-->
<arg0 wsu:Id="id-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568146638" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568147642" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#EK-374FDD240DA4088CF9146901568147640"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>A9cCXThSZz8lZzPSZftZUXB40KLM08w3Ck6+sc8dAbg=</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></arg0>
</soap:sayHello>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**UPDATE more**

This is my original SOAP message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.aaa.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:sayHello>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>Jina</arg0>
      </soap:sayHello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And Belows are my modified WSS configuration

- Signature

  Keystore : client keystore jks file

  Alias : client key alias

  Password : client private key password

  Key Identifier Type : X.509

  Parts : sayHello(Name), http://soap.aaa.com/ (Namespace),  Element (Encode)
- Encryption

  Keystore : client keystore jks file

  Alias : service key alias

  Password : empty

  Key Identifier Type : X.509

  Parts : sayHello (Name), http://soap.aaa.com/ (Namespace), Content (Encode)

*Ingoing WS-Security Configuration

```
Decrypt Keystore : client keystore jks file
Signature Keystore : client keystore jks file
Password - password of client's private key
```

This configuration throws no soap exception in SoapUI side. In SoapUI log only this message is shown

```
Sun Jul 24 08:59:51 KST 2016:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Sun Jul 24 08:59:51 KST 2016:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /SOAPSecurityWeb/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1
Sun Jul 24 08:59:52 KST 2016:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Sun Jul 24 08:59:52 KST 2016:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Sun Jul 24 08:59:52 KST 2016:INFO:Got response for [HelloWorldServiceSoapBinding.sayHello:Request 1] in 326ms (361 bytes)
```

The soap error response from SOAP service is like below

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
         <faultstring>An error was discovered processing the &lt;wsse:Security> header</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And in WS service side this exception is displayed

```
09:37:54,340 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-2) Interceptor for {http://soap.aaa.com/}HelloWorldService has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.createSoapFault(WSS4JUtils.java:216)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:329)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.AlgorithmSuiteValidator.checkSymmetricEncryptionAlgorithm(AlgorithmSuiteValidator.java:149)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.decryptDataRef(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:550)
```

And more the following exception are thrown when the SoapUI 5.2.1 starting, Do you think these exceptions are related with this issues?

```
Sun Jul 24 09:34:33 KST 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Sun Jul 24 09:34:33 KST 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
Sun Jul 24 09:34:33 KST 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Sun Jul 24 09:34:33 KST 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
```

**UPDATE LAST**

I deployed the same SOAP service on both Wildfly 8.2 and Wildfly 10. But the different exceptions are thrown.

**Wildfly 10 :**

```
15:44:53,834 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-2) Interceptor for {http://soap.aaa.com/}HelloWorldService has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A security error was encountered when verifying the message
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.createSoapFault(WSS4JUtils.java:216)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:329)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [myclientkey]
Original Exception was org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [myclientkey]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.getAsymmetricDecryptedBytes(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:301)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleToken(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:194)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleToken(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:76)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.engine.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:344)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:280)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [myclientkey]
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:632)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.getAsymmetricDecryptedBytes(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:259)
    ... 46 more
```

SOAP fault :

```
<faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://ws.apache.org/wss4j">ns1:SecurityError</faultcode>
<faultstring>A security error was encountered when verifying the message</faultstring>
```

**Wildfly 8.2 :**

```
WARNING [org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor] (default task-2) : org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleToken(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:163) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleToken(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:66) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:402) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:272) [cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:121) [cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:106) [cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) [cxf-api-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [myclientkey]
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:651) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleToken(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:142) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    ... 43 more
15:46:03,174 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-2) Interceptor for {http://soap.aaa.com/}HelloWorldService has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.createSoapFault(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:863) [cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:329) [cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:121) [cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:106) [cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) [cxf-api-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleToken(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:163) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleToken(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:66) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:402) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:272) [cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [myclientkey]
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:651) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleToken(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:142) [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]
    ... 43 more
```

SOAP fault :

```
<faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:FailedCheck</faultcode>
<faultstring>The signature or decryption was invalid</faultstring>
```

Do you have any idea? If you don't mind I can make another thread on this site with the wildfly version you want.

Comment: Your arg0 has no namespace? You need to enter the namespace into the Parts-table. It would also help if you add the contents of the "Raw"-tab of the request (not the response) after you send the request to the question. And perhaps the relevant part of the server log. Also have a look at the error log of SoapUI as it often contains helpful messages.

Comment: There are no error logs strangely. There are only http log.** HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: Undertow/1 Server: WildFly/10 Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 361 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:InvalidSecurity</faultcode><faultstring>An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope> **

Comment: Try to add `http://soap.aaa.com/` as the namespace of your Part (Screenshot 2). Be careful not to have any whitespaces if you copy&paste.

Comment: As you said I insert namespace like this 
= Parts : arg0 (Name), http://soap.aaa.com/ (Namespace) ,Content (Encode)
 Then error log is **ERROR:org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (WSEncryptBody/WSSignEnvelope: Element to encrypt/sign not found: {http://soap.aaa.com/}arg0) **
Then I modified parts of encryption and signature like below : **Parts : sayHello (Name), http://soap.aaa.com/ (Namespace) ,Content (Encode)** This time ** org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Signature creation failed (Cannot setup signature data structure)
** Your advice, pls!

Comment: `see error log for details` says you should log in the error log of SoapUI. I guess there's something wrong in the outgoing request so the security headers are not set correctly.

Comment: The thrown excepton is **Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [myclientkey] at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:651)  [wss4j-1.6.17.jar:1.6.17]** But my key generation command did not bring any error. These key works successfully in wildfly WAS.

Comment: Pls, inform me the meaning of this exception statement **"ERROR [org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin] (default task-44) Cannot find key for alias: [myclientkey] in keystore of type [jks] from provider [SUN version 1.8] with size [2] and aliases: {myservicekey, myclientkey}"** and how to solve it.

Comment: I do not know SOAPUI or wildfly but we have been playing a few days writing a WS Client requesting an https and we got this exception org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header. Actually we realized there was no such header at all and that was because our client java code missed adding a WSS4JOutInterceptor to inject the security header